# Value only returns 0

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a new student at programming and my college is teaching Java.

I was doing this exercise from my homework, and can't figure out why it only returns 0.

I've been looking at the internet for the past couple of days before I decided to post here.
I read somewhere that Java never changes the value 0 if I start the variable with it (i7 = 0), but even when I change to i7 =  1, it returns 0 and the array is no more of 8 indexes, but 7.
Also, wasn't it supposed to start filling the array at the moment I input numbers with the keyboard?
Maybe I misunderstood something?
How can I make it show the smallest number?

Thanks!

//Read and array of 8 indexes and find the smallest number

I have:

```
    int array1[] = new int[8];
    int i7;
    int smallest = array1[0];

    System.out.println("Type 8 numbers.");

    for (i7 = 0; i7 < array1.length; i7++)
    {
       array1[i7] = keyboard.nextInt();

       if (array1[i7] < array1[0])
       {
           smallest = array1[i7];
       }
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest number is " + smallest);
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? Since you are new and probably do not know how to use a debugger, you can place some print statements at the various code block boundaries that output the current state of the array and the current smallest number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize smallest to array1[0] which is still not initialized from user input - i.e. it starts with 0.

Now, to fix the above issue, you compare with array[0] instead of smallest in the `if` - but this isn't the right fix.

```
int array1[] = new int[8];
int i7;
System.out.println("Type 8 numbers.");
array1[0] = keyboard.nextInt();

int smallest = array1[0]

for (i7 = 1; i7 < array1.length; i7++)
{
   array1[i7] = keyboard.nextInt();

   if (array1[i7] < smallest)
   {
       smallest = array1[i7];
   }
}
System.out.println("The smallest number is " + smallest);
```

Alternate solution.

```
int array1[] = new int[8];
int i7;
int smallest;

System.out.println("Type 8 numbers.");

for (i7 = 0; i7 < array1.length; i7++)
{
   array1[i7] = keyboard.nextInt();

   if(i7 == 0)
   {
        smallest = array1[0];
   }
   else
   {
       if (array1[i7] < smallest)
       {
           smallest = array1[i7];
       }

   }
}
System.out.println("The smallest number is " + smallest);
```

I prefer the 1st one, though.

Comment: This still doesnt work..... What about here 'int smallest = array1[0]' smallest get init to 0;

Comment: @gbtimmon - nope - see the line before `int smallest = array[0];`. In my program array[0] is already initialized.

Comment: I would prefer a third solution where you always read the input in the `for` loop and initialize `smallest` with the max value on Integer using `int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`. In this way, the code is cleaner and has more readability.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - true dat.

Answer (score 1):

Below I have annotated your code with the location of problems or their cause:

```
int array1[] = new int[8];  // create an array of 8 ints. all are initially 0.
int i7;
int smallest = array1[0]; // set smallest to 0.

System.out.println("Type 8 numbers.");

for (i7 = 0; i7 < array1.length; i7++)
{
   array1[i7] = keyboard.nextInt(); // potential problem, what is 'keyboard'?

   if (array1[i7] < array1[0]) // compare last read against first read
   {
       smallest = array1[i7];
   }
}
System.out.println("The smallest number is " + smallest);
```

Now, here is what I would do to fix it:

```
int array1[] = new int[8];  // create an array of 8 ints. all are initially 0.
int i7;
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  // set the smallest to (2^31)-1; the largest int.

System.out.println("Type 8 numbers.");

for (i7 = 0; i7 < array1.length; i7++)
{
   array1[i7] = keyboard.nextInt();

   if (array1[i7] < smallest) // compare last read against current smallest
   {
       smallest = array1[i7];
   }
}
System.out.println("The smallest number is " + smallest);
```

Another potential source or problems is your call to `keyboard.nextInt()`. What class of object is `keyboard`? It could be returning 0 at each call. If you run the fixed code without supplying `0` as one of the inputs and still get `0` as the smallest, then you know that your `keyboard.nextInt()` call has problems.

Comment: keyboard is to get the numbers from the user =): Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

Answer (score 0):

`array1[i7] < array1[0]` always performs the exact same comparison; you want `array1[i7] < smallest`

In addition, `array1[0]` equals zero after it's initialized, so `smallest` will always equal 0 unless you're entering negative numbers.  Instead, initialize `smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE`. This will initialize `smallest` to the largest possible integer, so any numbers you enter will (probably) be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually asked the user for the numbers did you?

Try adding this before your for call:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

for(int z=0;z < 8;z++){
    array1[z] = new Integer(sc.nextLine()).intValue();
}
```

Comment: The line `array1[i7] = keyboard.nextInt()` fills the array. There could be an error at this line.